# Get Catalog Price Rules for Product

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules, price-rules

Given a product in Magento, how can I get a list of all the catalog price rules that apply to it? I know that I can use `getFinalPrice()` to get the price after all rules were applied; however, I am more interested in the catalog price rule objects themselves that apply to a given object.

Answer (score 0):

This solution would show you if a product has a rule applied maybe you can get which rule from this one somehow

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$connection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
$tableName = $resource->getTableName('catalogrule_product');
$count = $connection->fetchOne('SELECT COUNT(1) as c FROM '.$tableName.' WHERE product_id = '. $product->getId());

if ($count == 1) { 
    //you have a rule for the product
}
```